# Can I compose functions using std::bind*?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++20, function-composition, stdbind

I'm playing with functional programming in C++20 and write something like that:

```cpp
template <class OuterFn, class InnerFn, class... Args>
concept Composable =
    std::invocable<OuterFn, std::invoke_result_t<InnerFn, Args...>>;

template <class OuterFn, class InnerFn>
constexpr auto
compose(OuterFn&& outer, InnerFn&& inner)
{
    return [
        out = std::forward<OuterFn>(outer),
        in = std::forward<InnerFn>(inner)
    ]<class... Args>(Args && ... args)
        requires Composable<OuterFn, InnerFn, Args...>
    {
        using std::invoke, std::forward;
        return invoke(out, invoke(in, forward<Args>(args)...));
    };
}

template <class OuterFn, class InnerFn>
constexpr auto
operator*(OuterFn&& outer, InnerFn&& inner)
{
    using std::forward;
    return compose(forward<OuterFn>(outer), forward<InnerFn>(inner));
}

template <class... RestFn>
constexpr auto
compose(RestFn&&... rest)
{
    return (std::forward<RestFn>(rest) * ...);
}
```

This is work, but I want to refactor compose for two arguments by using std::bind* instead of lambda.
So, I think that this:

```
using eq_t = std::equal_to<const std::string_view>;
constexpr auto eq_42 = std::bind_front(eq_t{}, "42");
```

is clearly than(especially if using function without overloaded operator for it):

```
constexpr auto eq_42 = [](const std::string_view sv){ return sv == "42"; };
```

Maybe You have an ideas how can I do this, or reasons why I can't do this?

The problem is how to retrieve arguments to inner function.

`std::bind(outer, std::bind_front(inner));`
I tried this for variadic template arguments(and million other variants) by analogy from
`std::bind(outer, std::bind(inner, _1));` for one argument, but it doesn't work.

P.S. Sorry for my english)

Comment: Why would you abandon lambda and choose `std::bind`, which is outdated and not recommended?

Comment: Where did you hear that std::bind is outdated?
In my opinion, there are better(or simple, readable, laconic) ways for code composition than lambda.

Comment: `std::bind` is not "simple, readable, laconic" compared to a lambda

Comment: All depends on how you use it)

Comment: There are numerous recommendations to avoid `std::bind()`. For example, in [this CppCon video, at 25:08 .. 33:05](https://youtu.be/zt7ThwVfap0?si=rimgO8bwoZXH0nK5&t=1508) (already from 2015) about `<functional>`, Stephan T. Lavavej (the implementor of Visual Studio's C++ Standard Library) wraps it up by saying, "Avoid using `bind()`!" And as I understand, `std::bind()` is essentially an obsolete construct that was invented only because there were no lambdas yet in the C++ language.

Comment: I'm understand main reasons from video. Thanks.
By the way, std::bind appear in C++11 like lambdas, that's why this is even more stranger.
Although, I'm still think that all depends on how you use it)

Comment: Iirc `std::bind` was standardised pretty early, and then other things piled up, pushing back the publication by a number of years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace your template `compose` with an implementation using `std::bind`, because you would need to supply a variable number of placeholders to the `bind` call. The best you can do is support a specific arity of arguments to the inner call, up to the (implementation-defined) limit of how many `std::placeholders` there are.

Nor can you use `std::bind_front`, because a function object in general isn't the value it returns when called.

So you have to have an intermediate function object, holding the inner and outer functions, and the simplest syntax for that is a lambda. If you really wanted to, you could wrap that in `std::bind_front`, but there's no point.

```
template <class OuterFn, class InnerFn>
constexpr auto
compose(OuterFn&& outer, InnerFn&& inner)
{
    using std::invoke, std::forward;
    struct composer {
        template <class Out, class In, class... Args>
        auto operator()(Out&& out, In&& in, Args&&.. args) {
            return invoke(out, invoke(in, forward<Args>(args)...));
        }
    };
    // Fairly gratuitous bind_front, composer could have done the capturing of outer and inner itself
    return std::bind_front(composer{}, forward(outer), forward(inner));
}
```

Comment: that's why I wrote `std::bind*`, meaning `std::bind`, `std::bind_front`, `std::bind_back`

Comment: @hlebyshek the answer is still no, because you need to wait for the result of `inner` to have the argument to `outer`

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple of utility classes.

```
  #include <utility>
  #include <tuple>
  #include <functional>

  template <typename Func>
  struct wrap
  {
      wrap (Func func) : func{func} {}
      template <typename ... T>
      auto operator()(std::tuple<T...>&& args) {
          return std::apply(func, std::forward<std::tuple<T...>>(args));
      }
      Func func;
  };

  template <typename Func>
  struct unwrap
  {
      unwrap (Func func) : func{func} {}
      template <typename ... T>
      auto operator()(T&& ... args) {
          return func(std::tuple(std::forward<T>(args)...));
      }
      Func func;
  };
```

With this:

```
  template <typename Func1, typename Func2>
  auto compose (Func1 func1, Func2 func2)
  {
      using namespace std::placeholders;
      return unwrap(std::bind(func1, std::bind(wrap(func2), _1)));
  }
```

And a test:

```
  int foo(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
  int bar(int a) { return a*2; }

  int main()
  {
      std::cout << compose(bar, foo)(3,4);
  }
```

Conceptification and forwardification are left as an exercise for the reader.

But you should really forget about `std::bind` and use lambdas.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Extra code in my situation will be superfluous. I will put up with using lambda)